# How to apply sed here?

Tags: linux, shell, unix, sed, scripting

I have the following string -

```
<ROM readonly="false" persist="false" type="string" name="rom_code_url">ROMCODE_URL_VAL</ROM>
```

Now, I want to replace the the ROMCODE_UR_VAL to the following -

```
dvb://1000.b.2CEC.1/romcode_1.0.xml
```

How can I do so using SED?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's as simple as `'s/pattern/replacement/'` with proper escaping, or an equivalent expression. for example:

```
sed 's ROMCODE_URL_VAL dvb://1000.b.2CEC.1/romcode_1.0.xml ' <input-file>
```

NOTE: The trailing space is important as we're using spaces as delimiters, rather than forward slashes.

Comment: @jweyrich use a different delimiter, it will be more readable without all those backslashes.

Comment: also, why you have all those dots backslashed, i have no idea.  the rhs is not a pattern.

Comment: Good points! I just updated it to make it more readable. Thanks for the suggestion/hint!

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing this in a script, you can try something like piping from stdin:

```
awk -F"ROMCODE_UR_VAL" '{print $1"dvb://1000.b.2CEC.1/romcode_1.0.xml"$2}'
```

Comment: @RobbieDee Its not, but sometime an `awk` solution may be much better than a `sed` solution, and normally more easy to understand than `sed`.  All system I have seen that have  `sed` do also have `awk`.